How to validate the accounts passed on remaining_accounts in Anchor?
I'm wondering what would be the correct way to deal with multiple accounts in Anchor. For example, lets say that we have a program with User PDA accounts and multiple Data PDA associated to each user. Now, in the case of a single User and a single Data account associated to it I could do something like:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct UpdateUser<'info> {
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"USER", signer.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub user: Account<'info, UserAccount>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"DATA", signer.key().as_ref(), some_id_for_each_data.as_le_bytes()],
        bump
    )]
    pub data: Account<'info, DataAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>
}

which allows the user to modify both their account and the data one. But what if I want to alter many data accounts? I suppose I'd have to use the remaining_accounts property, but as far as I know it doesn't validate/deserialize the accounts passed, so is there a way around it?

You can check a remaining_account on deserialization, for example to try to load a remaining_account as a TokenAccount:
// for some: remaining_accounts: &[AccountInfo<'info>]
// i.e. &ctx.remaining_accounts

   let account_info = &remaining_accounts[i];

   let token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount> =
     Account::try_from(&account_info).map_err(|_| ErrorCode::SomeErr)?;

If you know the upper limit of how many data accounts will get passed, you may also find it easier to make your data accounts Optional and pass them the normal way:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct UpdateUser<'info> {
    #[account(
     // same as before...
    )]
    pub user: Account<'info, UserAccount>,

    #[account(
      has_one = user // < easier than seeds
    )]
    pub data1: Option<Account<'info, DataAccount>>,

    #[account(
      has_one = user
    )]
    pub data2: Option<Account<'info, DataAccount>>,
// etc...

}


Thank you for the explanation and examples!
